# DoM XSS in jquery

Tags: security, dom, xss

here is a DOM based vulnerability:
Query Versions Vulnerable to Selector XSS with class Attribute ('. XSS_VECTOR')
These jQuery libraries cause DOM XSS when a user controlled value is passed as a the class selected [$('.'+ className)]

But I don't know about the attack vector. Can you give me an example?

Comment: Any chance you can clear your question up? Use code tags for any code - and more code is needed to help you. [See here](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/DOM_Based_XSS) for general information though.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the action script (scroll down the page): http://domstorm.skepticfx.com/modules?id=529bbe6e125fac0000000003

You can see the result of the js "exploit" variable injection in DOM. (Un)fortunately jQuery, and the old versions, is such-alike.